# Use Config Manager in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

How can I use Azure Function app settings to fetch a non-string value? 
I use :

```
var resourceGroupName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["resourceGroupName"];
var dataFactoryName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dataFactoryName"];
```

But I can't do this for int/double variables. What is the way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the `string` value into either a `double` or an `int`:

```
double val;
if (double.TryParse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting"], out val))
{
    //use val
}
```

`double.TryParse` and `int.TryParse` will return `false` if the configuration value cannot be converted to a `double` or an `int` respectively.

Comment: For Azure Functions, you could use

    double val;
    double.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("YourAppConfigKey", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process), out val);